# Separate my html landing page from react app?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, routes

I want to have a separate set of `HTML` pages from my react app.

I've created this vanilla `HTML/ CSS/ JS` landing page that looks great. I'm trying to figure out how to make this my index page without actually adding it to my `React` app.

This is because of the various plugins I'm using that doesn't translate to `React`, and unique `CSS` code that I'd rather not have global.

Imagine loading to the home page, which is vanilla `HTML`. Then when the user hits the login button, it directs them to the React `/login` component. I have the routing set up so that referencing `/login` in an anchor will trigger `React`, I just need to get the `HTML` to be standalone.

Here's the way my app is currently set up.

```
reactapp
|
------server.js
|
------package.json
|
------boilerplate etc
|
------client
      |
       -------public
                |
                 -----index.html
                |
                -------landingHomePage.html
      |
      --------src
               |
               -----index.js
               |
               -----page1.js, page2.js, page3.js etc
```

in `reactapp/server.js`

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
console.log("PORT NUMBER IS " + port);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server Running on port ${port}`));
```

in `reactapp/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "reactexpress",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "react-express boilerplate",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  }, ...
```

in `reactapp/client/src/index.js`

```
ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <Layout>
       <Switch>
         <Route exact strict path={"/page1"} component={page1} />
         <Route exact path={"/page2"} component={page2} />
         <Route exact path={"/page3"} component={page3} />
         <Route exact path={"/login"} component={Login}/>
       </Switch>
    </Layout>
    </BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The CURRENT `index.html` is a standard `HTML` empty template with

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

If I rename the current html to something like `react.html` and rename `landingHomePage.html` to `index.html`, it gives errors.

Note: going to `url/landingHomePage.html` DOES direct me to the right page without any issues, but I want this to be `index.html` so it will go there by default.

Comment: What erros does it give you?

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this? If so, please post an answer :)